# If you pick an object from ground and place it at bookshelf.. it has gained potential energy

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, energy-conservation, work, potential-energy

If you pick an object from ground and place it at bookshelf.. it has gained potential energy but no change in kinetic energy.. does it violate law of  conservation of energy

Comment: No, because it clearly gained the energy from you. And you used stored chemical potential energy in your muscles, converted to kinetic energy that is then given to the object to convert into gravitational potential energy. You gained the chemical potential energy by eating food. The chain goes back to the Sun radiating away the mass energy from nuclear fusion.

Comment: But wait, I used an electric motor powered by a fission plant. My chain goes back to an even older star going supernova!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. Since you did work against the force of gravity, and the work done is converted into gravitational potential energy. To be specific, if you used your muscles, or an electric motor with a battery, the energy was previously chemical potential energy.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with this scenario is that your system is too complex: it has a human in it. That precludes simple analysis: how does a biological system use chemical energy to make mechanical energy? idk.

You could lift the book with a pulley, in which case you need some weight losing the same potential energy to raise the book.

Or, you could imagine the book is on a compressed ideal spring, which stored potential energy, and then lifts the book.

In both those cases you have to worry about the kinetic energy of motion going away, which involves damping.

In a simple system, damping means energy is not conserved, or, you have to included microscopic degrees of freedom and consider heat energy. That's not so simple either.